# Add a vote to convert a question to community wiki

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, voting

As far as I know, the only ways for a question to get converted to a community wiki are:

1. The original poster converts it.
2. A mod converts it.

Could we get a vote for this, just like there are to close or delete questions?

Comment: I was just about to post this as a feature request; glad to see it's already come up.  This would be useful to have available to users with a higher reputation, say 5k, 8k or 10k.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: there are two more ways for a question to get converted to community wiki; number of edits past a threshold and number of answers past a threshold. There is a FAQ with further details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11741#11741, near "How does a post become a Community Wiki post?".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as Community Wiki is a one-way street, I'm not sure this is a good idea.  If five people vote to close, five people can vote to reopen.  If five people vote to make CW, there is no going back.  Unless the site allows a question to go back and forth between CW and question (which I don't think it should), I think this will be a nightmare.

Comment: May be the amount of CW votes should be higher?

Comment: No, voyager, **lower**!

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that posts convert to CW after a number of edits - I think it's still 5.

So you can help force a question to CW by making an edit to it, but that would rely on 4 others making edits as well or the OP making several outside the 5 minute window, so it's neither effective nor particularly fair and I wouldn't recommend it.

The other method to community wiki is if there are enough answers to the question, 30 for SO and SF, 15 for SU.

Comment: That only works for the original poster. For someone else to force it into CW, there has to be five people, other than the OP, who edit it.

Comment: Ah - I'll update my answer.

Comment: The rule regarding edits is now: "The body of the post has been edited six (6) times by at least four (4) different people." or "The post has been edited eight (8) times by the original owner.". From a FAQ, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11741#11741, near "How does a post become a Community Wiki post?".

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want this? Is it to prevent people from getting reputation from something you think they shoudln't?

How about not upvoting a post you don't think it's deserving of reputation?
That seems enough for me.

Comment: When I initially posted this, there was someone attempting to game the system over on SO by opening a question, posting his own answer to said question, then changing the topic to a community wiki at a later time after people pointed out that these questions should be community wikis.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't upvote those posts

Answer (score 1):

I also was just getting into request this feature.  My idea was to make it at least 5 votes from 10K+ users, so it would only be visible by said group of users.

Comment: Yes, because "5 votes to delete a post" was already [never going wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50967/question-deletions-are-getting-out-of-hand).

Comment: @gnoupi: touche, good point....  blah...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same concerns that [Mathew has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29592/add-a-vote-to-convert-a-question-to-community-wiki/29598#29598).

I believe that as this is most likely to be a one way street, the vote threshold should be higher than any of the others. May be 10 or 15 votes may be? And may be coupled with the feature request of allowing for votes against CW to be able to be casted before converting? Meaning that if 5 users vote against turning to CW, it would be required 20 users to turn it to CW.

Comment: With these rules you do not have to implement it in the first place. The whiners win.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a "flag" option for "This ought to be a community wiki"? This way, it still remains in the hands of the moderators, but there's a convenient way to ask them to wiki-fy something. (The OP could also get a notification, such as "users have requested that this post be converted to community wiki.")

Comment: You can already do this using the custom flags.

Comment: @Mysticial I suppose. It seems like something that should be an automatic option, though.

Comment: I don't think so. (New) posts that *should* be wiki (and are suitable for the site) are rare enough anyways.