# Forcing a CW without being a mod

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, abuse, ethics

I came up with an idea while reading mmyers recent post.

We all know that there are some good questions out there that are subjective. They of course get closed because they are not Community Wiki.

Well, what if instead of closing, we just encouraged other people with edit privileges to slightly modify the question therefore, forcing it into a community wiki question.

I've never done this, but looking back I may have attempted it on some really good questions that shouldn't have been closed, just made CW.

Is this ethically wrong or abuse of the system?

Comment: Example of question? Also, CW is rarely an alternative to closing. If a question is closed, it's not the fact of putting it CW which would really change the fact that it should be closed, especially if you refer to subjective/argumentative questions.

Comment: @gnoupi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=subjective&sort=votes&pagesize=50 skip the first 2(they are locked)

Comment: Example of question to be saved, not of existing CW. And if you refer only to "subjective", then you are indeed wrong. Subjective shouldn't be allowed, that's all.

Comment: Here's a related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29592/add-a-vote-to-convert-a-question-to-community-wiki

Comment: I think it's pretty clearly abuse, but gave you +1 for bringing it up.

Comment: I kinda don't understand how I get -1s for an ethical question. Is it ethically wrong to ask an ethical quesiton? :)

Comment: @earlz: on Meta, downvotes often indicate disagreement with the premise of a post.  in this case, i'd interpret the downvotes as *"no, that's a bad idea"* -- as Bill says, it's actually good that you bring it up, but you're recommending an abuse of the system, so the downvotes aren't suprising.  don't be offended.

Comment: @quack, @earlz: Yes, my +1 was for bringing a potential exploit into the light, not an endorsement of it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wiki bullying should not be encouraged.  Editing is not a feature that's supposed to be abused in this manner.

If the question should be closed, vote to close it.  If the question isn't clear or useful, downvote it.  Note that there are NO suggestions that editing, closing or downvoting are to be used as tools to "encourage" a user to choose CW mode.  This negative, non-constructive behavior is discouraged.

Comment: @Polly yea, **your** the one to talk about editing abuse ;)

Comment: @earlz - *"yea, you're the one to talk about waffle abuse ;)"* ftfy

Comment: Just 'cause you can't edit comments? ;)

Answer (score 3):

They are not "closed because they are not CW"
If they are subjective, they should be closed as subjective.

CW is not a free pass to ask them.

Comment: Yes, but there are many subjective and accepted questions that are CW.

Comment: I call: Fallacy!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read  it's a question that is subjective, has no actual correct answer and yet it has 814 upvotes. If it were not CW, I'm pretty sure a mod would lock it due to the rep-fest.  (Also, it actually does add something good to the site)

Comment: no, that question exists because it was asked on Aug 4 '08 at 23:50 @ear

Comment: @earlz - CW does NOT prevent people to close questions or lock them. "Rep fest" is not the point here.

Answer (score 2):

This has been done before, mainly on old FAQ posts in the early days of SO.

Another techique I've seen is to post 30 answers and then delete them all. This also wikifies any existing answers.

I can't say that I'm in favor of either, though. If a question should be wiki, flag it for a moderator's attention (odds are it will hit 30 answers soon enough anyway). If it doesn't belong, close it rather than forcing it to wiki.

Comment: Well like I said, some posts are good on-topic questions, but they don't have an actual answer and therefore rep should not be given out for opinions.

Comment: Then flag them.

Comment: But flagging is for whimps. lol

Comment: +1 because I'd never heard of the "post 30 answers and then delete them all" method.  Please flag this sort of behavior if you see it in the wild.

Comment: @Bill: I think it was Shog9, and I only saw it once or twice. That was long ago.

Comment: The annoying thing about "post and delete 30 answers" is that I've got >10K rep on SO.  I get to see all of those 30.