# Convert to comment

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, comment-voting

Just like there is a "vote to delete" system I would like a "vote to convert to comment". So when an answer is clearly not an answer I can vote for it to be made a comment. If X people vote the same way it is converted.

Comment: While I like the idea, I imagine it will get shot down or ignored, just like [vote to community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29592/15880) did.

Comment: This [has been suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/70039#70039) as a 20k power.

Comment: The main issue will be where to pin the comment.  Some of these responses may be comments on other answers rather than the question.

Comment: I have suggested this be implemented as a moderator power: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments

Answer (score 9):

This is now implemented, moderators can convert posts to comments.

If you think something should be a comment please flag it.

Comment: We seriously need to move this to 10k mods.