# Change moderator convert to comment from input text to select option

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, moderator-tools

It's common to run across an answer as a comment by a new user and moderators have the option to delete the answer or move the answer comment with the radio selection **convert to comment**.  However, not all answers are needed for the question, which is the default option for the moderator:

[image]

If a moderator needs to covert the answer to a comment on another answer the solution I've always known to exist is to click on the answer user to and get the answer link in their answer box which is not a very good option if the user is of high rep.  After searching I didn't see this asked before but ran across other, similar questions regarding flagging:

- [Convert to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71284/convert-to-comment)
- [Proposed improvement to flagging, for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110404/proposed-improvement-to-flagging-for-answers)
- [Provide a tool for moderators to migrate comments to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat)

Can we change the default text field to a select option with the default as the question and the remaining selections the answers for the post?

Comment: I'd love a multiple choice option here too, but for what it's worth, you can use the "share" link on an answer to get a link to it, no need to go looking on user profiles.

Answer (score 5):

As Jefromi [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286092/change-moderator-convert-to-comment-from-input-text-to-select-option#comment928021_286092) I just copy the share link from the answer and paste that into the text box.

You don't even have to close the dialog to do this.

Comment: Unless you're on your mobile. I realize that moderating from a mobile is challenging at best, but that doesn't mean we can't wish for better :)